# how to enable the comment buttons in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

[image]I am using visual studio.
In the tool bar,"comment" and "uncomment" buttons are disabled.
and If I use <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>` also ,I am not able to comment the code.
how to solve this?

Comment: Please post a screenshot (I wonder if you're currently debugging, or have something opened where commenting does not apply).

Comment: What language is the source code file that you are editing?

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>CTRL + K + C</kbd> not <kbd>CTRL + K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> :)

Comment: You can check here if your shortcut is good : Tolls > Options > Environment > Keyboard then in "Press shortcut key" field type CTRL+K, CTRL+C => Edit.CommentSelection

Answer (score 0):

You need to select some text with your mouse to use those buttons. You also can't be in a state where editing is locked (such as while debugging).

Comment: I have selected the text.In normal mode also it is not in enable state.